# How i can load only my registered places in google places?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

I'm using Google Places.

When I load the XML, I want only the places I have registred in my account. I don't want all results.

How I can do that?

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=&name={myClienteName}&sensor=false&key={myClienteKey}
```

Comment: by registered in your account, i hope you are referring to your google places for business account and the listings you created with that. am i correct?

Comment: Yeah.
I uploaded a excel file with the informations of some stores, i want only the result of my stores. (are +2.000 stores)